# How to interpret Q-Q plots by comparing axis and the plotted points?

Tags: interpretation, qq-plot

One can interpret QQ plots by considering the values read from the axes compared for given plotted points. And if the data were well described by a normal distribution, the values should be about the same. But how to interpret the following plot, when the values are not the same? For example in the picture below (log returns), the point bottom far left corner: its y value is -0.20 and its x value is well past -2. What is the corresponding value of y to x value -2? And what is the corresponding value of x to y value -0.2?[image: Oman index log returns]

Here is the code I used in R program with `evir` package:
`qqnorm(X)`

The data X is log returns of Oman Muscat Price index.

Here are the mean 0.000023 and StDev 0.010896.

According to answer by Nick Cox would the corresponds be (data - mean)/ SD = (-0.2 - 0.000023) / 0.010896 = -18.36 ...

Comment: Could you please specify the code you used to draw this plot, and the software? I would say that something is wrong with the plot. You also can provide the data you used, and it will be possible to figure out how the right qqplot would look like and what's wrong with the y-axis. My "hypothesis" is that you have quite a lot of large outliers and you did not show them on this plot (I mean your distribution is not even close to normal and the outliers arised "assuming" the normal distribution).

Comment: Your distribution looks roughly  normal (Gaussian) in the middle (often happens; this has been dubbed WInsor's principle) but longer-tailed than normal otherwise. At a guess you are showing values with mean nearly zero but SD much less than 1. If so, that's OK but you expect proportionality not equality with a normal with mean 0 and SD 1 which is the reference distribution here.

Comment: Some programs adjust the scale on the x axis by multiplying by the observed SD and adding the observed mean. Then the reference case is equality.

Comment: Correction: if your mean is not 0 then the correspondence is just that the horizontal scale is a standard normal $N(0, 1)$ so corresponds to (data $-$ mean) / SD.

Comment: Your edit is the wrong way round. mean = 0.000023; sd = 0.010896 so 
mean $+$ [(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2) $\times$ sd] yields axis labels of -.021769   -.010873    .000023    .010919    .021815  on your scale.

Comment: The major point is that you don't have anything like a normal distribution, so the next question is what do you have.

Comment: I think my edit should be allright. Lets try this once more, mean+[(-18, -2,) x sd] = 0.000023+(-18 x 0.010896) = -0.1961 ,which is basically near that -0.2 point in the graph above. Then the next one 0.000023+(-2 x 0.010896)= -0.021769, which is the same as Nick Cox mentions above.

Comment: That is, your lowest value is about 18 sd below the mean: that is further evidence against a normal distribution.

Comment: what is the basis for asserting "*if the data were well described by a normal distribution, the values should be about the same*"?

Comment: Glen_b, maybe I just meant that the plotted points should not deviate much from the 45 degree slope.